# Creating a thread for parallel execution

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I have to call 2 APIs, need the first service result and then return that service result, but before returning that result, I want to create a thread and call 2nd service but i dont want to wait for its output.
Is this the correct way to do it ?

The service in Run method is the 2nd service which i want to run in parallely.

```
class Test implements ServiceA, Runnable
{

    private final ServiceA one; private final ServiceA two;
private TInput inputVar;
    Test(ServiceA one, ServiceA two)
       {
        this.one = one;
        this.two= two;
       }

    @override
    public objectA calculate(TInput input)
    {
        objectA objAOne = one.Find(input);
    inputVar = input;
    new Thread().start(); // Here, just want to call and return the result of objOne

        return objAOne ;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {   
     two.Find(input)    
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me on this ?

Comment: replace `new Thread().start();` with: `new Thread( new Test(one, two) ).start();`

Comment: @Krokodilko can you explain me what this will do ?

Comment: Please study some tutorial about threads, there are plenty of them out there, for example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm. This topis is broad, I can hardly explain this better that tutorials

Comment: @krokodilko thanks. Just want to know what your line of code is doing, was I having incorrect syntax ? Or is to run that thing in parallel so 1st api won't be blocked?